# How to display numbers(1,2,3,..) in CardView items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `CardView` items like this [image: image description here] and I want to display numbers in card view items like this [image: image description here]

What can I do in adapter to display numbers like 1,2,3.. ?depends upon size?im using retrofit to display data

Here is my adapter :

```
public class TipsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TipsAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
List<TipsModel> employees;
 Context context;

public TipsAdapter(Context context,List<TipsModel> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.tipstrickitem, parent, false);

    return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
   // TipsModel employee = employees.get(position);
    holder.employeeName.setText(employees.get(position).getTips());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return employees.size();
    //return (employees == null) ? 0 : employees.size();

}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView employeeName;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        employeeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.employeeName);

    }
}}
```

alignment got disturb:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSK7s.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change 
`holder.employeeName.setText(employees.get(position).getTips());`

to `holder.employeeName.setText(" " + position + ". " + employees.get(position).getTips());`

This will add the position of each element of the recycler view as a number before the Tips.

If you want to skip zero replace position with `String.valueOf(position+1)`

Comment: 0  is also getting displayed.i don't want 0

Comment: holder.employeeName.setText(" " + position + ". " + employees.get(String.valueOf(position+1)).getTips());
 getting error in get(String.valueOf(position+1))

Comment: @winij I meant the first position when it's used as a string like so: holder.employeeName.setText(String.valueOf(position+1) + ". " + employees.get(position).getTips());

Comment: alignment got disturb...see ss above..what to do?

Comment: @winij In my answer, I'd added a space at the beginning. Either remove that or copy and paste the code from my previous comment. I don't have an IDE to test my code, I'm just typing it from my mobile

Comment: hiii..can you help me out here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532667/particular-titlefetched-from-api-using-searchview

Comment: @Wini not sure If I could add anything more to the thread, sorry!